# Simple SMTP Processing point

Tags: python, email, smtp

I'm working with a third party service that will send update information on some machinery to an email address I specify. What I want to do is take that email, parse  out the the owner of a particular piece of hardware, and send that owner an email update. To be clear, I can't send the first email directly to the end user because the third party source I'm working with doesn't have my end user's email address data.

I've been able to do the two parts [(1)receiving+parsing, (2) sending new message ] independently using the smtpd and smtplib python packages, but I'm not able to use them together. Python doesn't have a builtin MTA so any outgoing messages I send with smtplib are intercepted by the smtpd.SMTPServer. Is there any way I can combine these two parts (receiving+parsing and sending an update) with a simple script without having to invest in a big smtp server package like Lamson?

Comment: Just curious why you don't just get the mail from an existing mail server... use python to check via POP3/IMAP and then send out to that same server?

Comment: @clutton I know that I could do that but I'm trying to avoid putting username/password data on the server that'll run the code. The company I work for has a server where I could send the emails, but if I use an SMTP client to access the data I'll have to update the password every time it expires. I also don't want to leave a password lying around in a config file if I can help it.

Comment: How is your script going to get mail?  Normally you get it from a mail server as that is where mail is delivered... I think you may be missing a piece, perhaps this helps: http://xmodulo.com/how-mail-server-works.html